# QML: Text element and antialiasing on Symbian device

Tags: qt, fonts, symbian, qml, antialiasing

I’m developing a simple program with Symbian^3 Qt 4.7.3. User interface is constructed with QML and contains Text elements. I use FontLoader to load custom font and use Nokia 500 as a testing device.

In simulator (Mac) text rendering looks great…

http://korkalainen.net/text_qt_simulator_mac.jpg

…but in Nokia 500 the antialiasing looks like this (in my opinion it’s awful):

http://korkalainen.net/text_nokia500.jpg

Is there any way to improve or change the antialiasing settings used on the device? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that problem too. The only solution was to go back to use the fonts preinstalled on the device.

Comment: I agree, looks like this is the only solution. Thanks.